# Sending a POST request through Swift

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am using Stripe API on the backend to process payments.
Here is the API URL:  http://localhost:2000/charge/new

I am using SwiftUI for my iOS application to send a POST request to my API.

Here is my DTO object:

DTO:

```
struct ChargeObjectDTO : Codable{
    let vendorCustomerID: String;
    let currency: String;
    let chargeValue: CLongDouble;
    let confirmationStatus: Bool;
}
```

This is my request logic, I am trying to send a POST request with ChargeObjectDTO as an object:

**PaymentsAPI:**

```
    func createChargeRequest(chargeObj: ChargeObjectDTO) throws {
     
        var url = “http://localhost:2000/charge/new"
    
        do{
            //send request
            guard let myReqURL = URL(string: url) else { throw NetworkResponse.error };
            
            //Request
            var request = URLRequest(url: myReqURL);
            request.httpMethod = "POST";
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: chargeObj);
            
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")   //Here is where we add tokens, like authentication tokens
            
           
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                          httpResponse.statusCode == 200,
                          let myData = data,
                          let myJson = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data!, options: []) else{
                        let message = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to Decode Response from Server"
                        print(message)
                        return
                    }
                    print("Created Payment Intent");
                    //DispatchQueue.main.async
                    
                }).resume();
                
                
                
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
      
        
       
    }
```

Here is the UI screen
**BookHotel:**

```
    struct HotelBookingScreen: View {

        @State var myPaymentsAPI: PaymentsAPI = PaymentsAPI.init(chargeObjectDTO: ChargeObjectDTO(vendorCustomerID: "", currency: "", chargeValue: 0, confirmationStatus: false));
    
  

        var body: some View {

            Button(action: {
                                    try? myPaymentsAPI.createChargeRequest(chargeObj: ChargeObjectDTO(vendorCustomerID: "cus_12345”, currency: "USD", chargeValue: 100, confirmationStatus: true))
                                    
                                },  label: {
                                    Text("Confirm")
                                        .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                     });

        }
    }
```

What is the problem, why I am getting this error even though, I am decoding the JSON object?

The Error I am getting is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

Comment: `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: chargeObj)` that's the line causing the error. It's about Encoding, not decoding. `ChargeObjectDTO` is `Codable` so use `JSONEncoder` not `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: And don't use `try ?`. Use `do/try/catch` rather than throwing away errors.

Comment: Unrelated, but we don't need `;` in Swift (in rare case only if there are multiple instruction in a single line), and generally speaking, avoid using `try?` (with a question mark) unless you know how to decode, use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch` and print the error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved my problem, hope it helps someone.

Code:

```
class PaymentsAPI: ObservableObject{

let paymentsAPI = URL.paymentsAPIURL;

var endpoint: String;


init(endpoint: String) {
    self.endpoint = endpoint
}



func createChargeRequest(chargeObj: ChargeObjectDTO, completion: @escaping(Result<ChargeObjectDTO, NetworkResponse>) -> Void) {
 
    let myURL = "\(paymentsAPI)\(endpoint)"


    do{
        guard let reqURL = URL(string: myURL) else{ throw NetworkResponse.error }
        //Request
        var request = URLRequest(url: reqURL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(chargeObj)
        
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
            guard let myHttpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, myHttpResponse.statusCode == 200,
                  let jsonData = data else{
                completion(.failure(NetworkResponse.error))
                return
            }
            
            do{
                let messageData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ChargeObjectDTO.self, from: jsonData)
                completion(.success(messageData))
            }catch{
                completion(.failure(.error))
            }
        }
        
        dataTask.resume()

    }catch{
        completion(.failure(.error))
    }
    
}
```

}